# Redux: share a regex between back and front-end

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I need to share some static data between my rails app and the redux-based front-end. The example in this case is a regular expression used by a helper method in the js and also in a controller in the rails app.

I feel it's annoying having to add something like this into the redux store since the store is not easily connected to from independent helper files in the js. Instead you would need to grab it in `mapStateToProps`, pass it as a prop into a presentational component, that would then send it through in an action, so that the code that handles actions (either in `mapDispatchToProps` or reducer) could send it through as a param when using the helper method.

Seems like a lot of unnecessary passing around for something that never changes. Are there any standards for static data provided by the server to be used in the front-end? Maybe adding something to the window object?

Comment: Why not make it `const` and expose it as a utility method which you can directly import in your front-end JS wherever needed? In other words, why does the frontend components need to pass the regex (which is supposedly a constant) as a param to the helper method in the first place?

Comment: @Mrchief yes I'd like to do something like that, but it should be shared across the server code (in this case rails) and the front-end code. It doesn't need to be passed around as params, I was saying that would be a downside of having it in the store.

Comment: Don't have any idea about Rails so can't help you there. I'd say build an API but that'd be an overkill if it's just one item.

Answer (score 0):

If its something that truly never changes, here are some ideas:

- Have a configuration endpoint where you can get the regex and drop into redux state
- Static config file that can be shared by JS/Ruby code
- Hardcode the regex directly into the reducer's initialState
- Create a javascript file and hardcode the regex directly into that file. Maybe put it in a file indicating its shared with the server.
- Using the window object will make all serious react devs cringe a little. Eventually, that value could change, and it is going to cause bugs all over your app. If you are confident to make that gamble, then do it. Using the window object may make testing more difficult as well.